# How to Apply UV maps to each face

Tags: uv

So I spent about an hour going through and UV editing each face for a building(walls, stairs, ect).[image]

but when I render it, it shows no textures.[image]

I have already changed it from generated to UV

Comment: Add a material and a texture to the object

Comment: I've done that and all that happens is it completly covers the whole object with that one texture, instead of each individual face.

Comment: Change the image mapping from Generated to UV

Comment: I have already done this for each object

Comment: @BoonaBurns if you don't mind uploading the *.blend file we might be able to help you a little easier

Answer (score 1):

- You must apply a new texture with the file with check box. Image Texture. Open the image file.
- Enable the texture
- Change the mapping to UV.
- Select the UV name explicitly to ensure it exists.
- You will be able to see the preview with the texture.
- Get some texture to appear then correct it.  Do not turn off the texture.

However if you really get stuck.

- If you have changed many settings on the texture the situation may be difficult. So keep the UV(the hard work).  Delete the texture in the texture panel. And start a texture fresh with newly minted settings as above.  When you are close to perfect the preview will reflect some change.  Focus on your fresh settings, not some from 2 hours ago. Start fresh.  This is really 5 minutes or less of work.  When the situation improves include a new screen shot of texture settings.